# Implementing autoNumeric v4 in MVC Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, bundle, autonumeric.js

I have a problem when I try to install via nuget manager, when I search for 'autonumeric' I can clearly see that the latest version is 1.9.45

When I go to [project site](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric), I can see that version 1.9.45 is obsolete.
So, I want to get version 4.* but I do not know how. I also tried vie npm install command and nothing.

My question is: How can I download and incorporate the new version of autoNumeric in my MVC Web Project?

Steps:

1. Download zip from GitHub [link](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric)
2. Unzip the folder and navigate to src folder
3. Copy all files to your solution for example to: Scripts/autoNumeric folder
4. Add it in your bundle like:

   > bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/autoumeric").Include(
   >                        "~/Scripts/autoNumeric/AutoNumeric.js",
   >                        "~/Scripts/autoNumeric/AutoNumericDefaultSettings.js",
   >                        "~/Scripts/autoNumeric/AutoNumericEnum.js",
   >                        "~/Scripts/autoNumeric/AutoNumericEvents.js",
   >                        "~/Scripts/autoNumeric/AutoNumericHelper.js",
   >                        "~/Scripts/autoNumeric/AutoNumericOptions.js",
   >                        "~/Scripts/autoNumeric/AutoNumericOptions.js",
   >                        "~/Scripts/autoNumeric/main.js"));
5. For testing purposes add in your HTML input field:

   ```
   <input type="text" id="test" value="" placeholder="something">
   ```
6. Initialize input field in your file. FOr example your main javascript file is main.js (NOTICE: this main.js is different than main.js in autonumeric folder!):

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     // Initialization
      new AutoNumeric('#test', { currencySymbol : '$' });
   })
   ```

This not works.
Question: Should I import ES modules from folder or my main.js 'sees' the autoNumeric/main.js and all of its modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on an internet connection you should probably just use a CDN

Here is the link : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/autonumeric

Simply import it in your body like :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autonumeric/4.1.0/autoNumeric.min.js"></script>
```

And you should be good using it (don't forget to remove useless files).

Comment: Do note that instead of relying on a fixed version, you can just use what the [documentation says](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/#in-the-browser) about that : `<script src="https://unpkg.com/autonumeric"></script>`. That way you always get the latest version.